# How to exclude cshtml from pre compilation during publish

Tags: visual-studio, razor, hangfire, postal

I have cshtml files in a c# web forms project that I want to publish using a publish profile that has the options:

- Allow precompiled site to be updateable = false

I am using Postal outside of ASP.net http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html as the emails that are being sent are from a background process. This is using hangfire and is very similar to this: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html

The problem is that the cshtml file is being precompiled when I dont want it to be and the resulting content of the file is:

> This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

I need the full contents of the original cshtml file and don't want the marker contents but I do also want to retain the setting of `Allow precompiled site to be updateable = false` so all other files can not be updated.

The only way I can see to do this is to have `Allow precompiled site to be updateable = true`

In short I want to deploy the cshtml in the same way that images files are when their build action is set to content.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Seems that someone else has the exact same problem:

[Is there a way to exclude certain .cshtm files, or an entire folder, from the 'precompile' option so that the .cshtml files can be used outside MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395961/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-certain-cshtm-files-or-an-entire-folder-from-the-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there was no way from excluding cshtml (or any other) files from the aspnet_compiler.exe. That means that cshtml will be precompiled along with everything else - there is no way that I could find to get around it.

The way I got this to work was to deploy 'extra' files as part of the publish, rather than have them a part of the web project itself.

This article explains in detail how you can deploy extra files outside of the visual studio project:

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying Extra Files](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files)

In your *.pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>UAT</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="..\ExtraFiles\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>    
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Place your 'extra files' in a folder called 'ExtraFiles' in the parent directory of the root of your web project and they will be copied over during publish.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using .pubxml, you can add Target after `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy` at the end of your .csproj file. It copies data from any number of sources to package folder, after files are prepared for packaging and before packaging starts:

```
<Target Name="AdditionalFilesForPackage" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
    <Message Text="AdditionalFilesForPackage(): MSBuildProjectDirectory -&gt; $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
    <Message Text="AdditionalFilesForPackage(): _PackageTempDir -&gt; $(_PackageTempDir)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <FolderFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FolderName\**\*" />
        <OtherCshtmlFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\OtherCshtml\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FolderFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(FolderFiles->'$(_PackageTempDir)\FolderName\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    <Message Text="AdditionalFilesForPackage(): Done copying FolderName files." />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(OtherCshtmlFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(OtherCshtmlFiles->'$(_PackageTempDir)\OtherCshtml\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    <Message Text="AdditionalFilesForPackage(): Done copying OtherCshtml files." />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Views can be kept precompiled when, after publishing, the view files for you emails are overwritten again with the originals again.

I perform this step manually for now, by overwriting the email view files via FTP.

Comment: If you check out the selected answer, you'll be able to see how you can automate this as part of your publish.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I'm not using the RazorViewEngine directly, but loading .cshtml from the file system instead). I changed the `.cshtml` to `.html` and it stopped being part of the compilation.